# Where can I get php_mysql.dll for Windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, windows-xp, php5

I just installed Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.2.14, and MySQL 5.1.51 on Windows XP. Apache is working and is loading PHP properly, but when I try to connect to MySQL, I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()". After some googling, I found that I need to load the php_mysql.dll extension, which requires libmysql.dll. I found the libmysql.dll file in the MySQL distribution, but php_mysql.dll is nowhere to be found.

Why is it not included with PHP or MySQL? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.2.14-Win32-VC6-x86.zip as downloaded from http://windows.php.net/download/ does include php_mysql.dll. It's in the "ext" subdirectory.

You'll need to rename `php.ini-recommended` to `php.ini`. Then, edit `php.ini` and make sure that `extension_dir` is pointing to the correct directory, i.e. the one containing php_mysql.dll, e.g. `c:\php\ext`. Also, search for the line `;extension=php_mysql.dll` and uncomment it to enable the extension.

Lastly, the file `libmysql.dll` should be available to the Windows system PATH. The easiest way to accomplish that is by [adding the directory to which you installed PHP to your PATH](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath).

Remember to restart Apache after making changes to php.ini. Hope this helps!

Comment: I copied that file into the php directory and now httpd crashes when I try to connect to the database. At least I have the DLL now! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> MySQL is no longer enabled by default,
>   so the php_mysql.dll DLL must be
>   enabled inside of php.ini. Also, PHP
>   needs access to the MySQL client
>   library. A file named libmysql.dll is
>   included in the Windows PHP
>   distribution and in order for PHP to
>   talk to MySQL this file needs to be
>   available to the Windows systems PATH.
>   See the FAQ titled "How do I add my
>   PHP directory to the PATH on Windows"
>   for information on how to do this.
>   Although copying libmysql.dll to the
>   Windows system directory also works
>   (because the system directory is by
>   default in the system's PATH), it's
>   not recommended.

[PHP/MySQL Installation manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php)

Comment: Yes, I've already read all of that. It says "the php_mysql.dll DLL must be enabled inside of php.ini" but I don't have php_mysql.dll.